# Finding People within specified distance of given latitude and longitude

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am writting PHP Application, where i need to find all people within specified distance from given latitude and longitude.
**Note:** I do know, other/all people's latitude and longitude,

But, how can i find all longitude and latitude that comes within certain mile / kilometer radius from my latitude and longitude.

How can i calculate that ? 
**Kindly note**: do no suggest me calculating all people distance within given latitude and longitude, as there may be 1000 people registered and calculating each people distance and matching with my radius will be big time consuming.

I would love to have reverse formula like :- I know distance, i know my latitude and longitude, and i do some calulation and i get all other people who are within my specified distance of latitude and longitude.

Example :-For an instance, my latitude is 15 and longitude is 30, than all other people within 5 km of  radius should be shown in list.

Here are few people who are stored in my db :- (people lat and long too changes quite often)

Person A :- lat (20) long (24)

Person B :- lat (15) long (19)

Person C :- lat (22) long (19)

Person D :- lat (20) long (24)

Person E :- lat (15) long (19)

Person F :- lat (22) long (19)

Person G :- lat (20) long (24)

Person H :- lat (15) long (19)

Person I :- lat (22) long (19)

and so on and so forth with aprox 1000+ user list.

From lat and long, i mean latitude and longitude respectively above.

Below is harversine formula, but it is of no use to me, as this will take huge time to achieve my target.

```
    <?php
    function getLatLong($address) {
        $address = str_replace(' ', '+', $address);
        $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $geoloc = curl_exec($ch);
        $json = json_decode($geoloc);

        return array($json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat, $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
    }

    $address = getLatLong('Guildford');
    $address = getLatLong('BH15 2BT');
    $address = getLatLong('10 Downing Street, London');

    function Haversine($start, $finish) {
        $theta = $start[1] - $finish[1];

        $distance = (sin(deg2rad($start[0])) * sin(deg2rad($finish[0]))) + (cos(deg2rad($start[0])) * cos(deg2rad($finish[0])) * cos(deg2rad($theta))); 
        $distance = acos($distance); 
        $distance = rad2deg($distance); 
        $distance = $distance * 60 * 1.1515;

        return round($distance, 2);
    }

    $start = getLatLong('Guildford');
    $finish = getLatLong('BH15 2BT'); 
    $distance = Haversine($start, $finish);

    print('<p>The distance between ['.$start[0].', '.$start[1].'] and ['.$finish[0].', '.$finish[1].'] is '.$distance.' miles ('.($distance * 1.609344).' km).</p>');
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: Better. I've voted to re-open the question now you have improved it, but in future you should always give this sort of detail from the very beginning, if you wish to avoid downvotes and having your question closed.

Comment: I am not at all convinced by your Haversine implementation. Presumably you've not tested it?

Comment: I have tested it, it shows distance between 2 latitude and longitude, but i need to know other people's latitude and longitude from given distance and 1st point latitude & longitude.

Comment: Well, you know other people's latitude and longitude already, right? So just iterate over your database and compute the distances, and filter out everyone who is too far away. You could do a faster pre-filter step with, say, the Manhattan distance, in order to cut down the amount of comuptation needed on a large dataset. Optimise later.

Comment: Exactly that is the problem. I do know, other people's latitude and longitude, but there are people who are not even in range and for my purpose, i need to calculate with their latitude and longitude too, it is not only resource consumption, but high time taking method. It would be best if i can know all the ranges that lies within radius.

Comment: Your question does not make this clear. Please update it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54115/discussion-between-john-cargo-and-rook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the points are in a database, you could check [this out](http://www.arubin.org/files/geo_search.pdf) (pdf link) which offers two alternatives. For a simple alternative the presentation suggests having a bounding box from the distance. Any points that are not within the box is filtered out leaving lesser points to do the Haversine on. So something like:

```
$address=[1.352083,103.81983600000001];

$distancePerDegree= 111.045; //km. 63 for miles
$withinDistance=1;

$latRange=[
    $address[0]-$withinDistance/$distancePerDegree,
    $address[0]+$withinDistance/$distancePerDegree
];

$lonRange=[
    $address[1]-$withinDistance/abs(cos(deg2rad($address[0]))*$distancePerDegree),
    $address[1]+$withinDistance/abs(cos(deg2rad($address[0]))*$distancePerDegree)
];

//gets rough points
$points=DB::fetchAll( //lets say this class queries the database.
 "SELECT lat,lon FROM points WHERE
  lat between ? and ? AND
  lon between ? and ?",
  [$latRange[0],$latRange[1],$lonRange[0],$lonRange[1]]
);

//filters using harversine
$points=array_filter($points,function($p){ 
    return Haversine($address,[$p->lat,$p->lon])<=$withinDistance;
});
```

This could probably cleaned up but should be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

have a look here:

Selecting points within a bounding circle
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html